# Is it possible to open links in chromium in other browser?

Tags: chromium

I still use Opera 12 as my primary browser. However, it is too slow for some pages (gmail and Facebook), so I started to use chromium for those. However, I would like to open links from chromium in Opera. Is that possible? Possibly via a middle click. (I am on Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: The other direction (Opera URL » Chromium) would easily work, but Chromium to Opera? I guess an extension is needed for this job.

Comment: And there is not such extension, right:-)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's [theoretically possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538313/google-chrome-extension-and-batch-command) since [Simple-Get](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/) also passes an URL to an external programm.

Comment: Is it possible that it only works for Chrome and not for Chromium? It tells me extensions cannot be added from that site.

Comment: HM, that works nicely enough. I would vote this for an answer if you provided it as such. Only if it could be configured to be launched via middle click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SimpleGet](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/), which normally is used to pass multiple URLs to an external download manager.

But you can modify the path and point it straight to Opera.

[image]

As a downside you have to perform two clicks extra and handle an awkward dialog to select the right URL. Since its source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/repinel/SimpleGet) it may be possible to tweak this part.

Answer (score 1):

Although it would technically be possible to open links in another browser, I am not aware of any method that would do so.

Even if you could open links in another browser, there would be issues in doing so.  Cookies and other session related information would not be passed to the new browser.  This would break the functionality of most websites.

Why not just run two browsers?  Or conversely, why not just switch to Chrome?

EDIT:  Well duh...  I forgot I run IE Tab in Chrome.  So yes, it is possible open links in a different browser - at least with an extension (no session info is passed).

Comment: Ehm, because in everything else but speed and site compatibility, all browers but opera suck big way from my point of view. I will eventually have to do it, but not just yet.

Cookies and stuff would not be an issue normally, as I would use chromium just for Facebook and Gmail and everything else would be handled by Opera.

Comment: @sup - Chrome and Opera currently use the same rendering engine.

Comment: I know, and Opera is no longer usable thanks to that. I still use version 12.